# I have publish my library to jcenter but I still can't get it through gradle

Tags: android, jcenter

My publish result looks like the picture.
[image]

But I still get the errot hint

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.leaking.slideswitch:slideswitch:1.0.0

The link is https://bintray.com/leaking/maven/SlideSwitch/view

Comment: can you please add the link to your package to the question?

Comment: @JBaruch https://bintray.com/leaking/maven/SlideSwitch/view